# The re-installed vista cannot support the second monitor

Tags: windows-vista

I re-installed vista on my lenovo R61 notebook. Everything seems fine except the following issue:

I am trying to add another LCD as the second monitor.
I double clicked the "display settings", but the system just cannot find the second monitor that is connected.

Comment: This is a sysadmin question, not a programming question. Try over at Server Fault instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the manufacturer's display driver.  It should either be on a disc you got with the laptop or on their website.